# What is the best way of creating greenDAO DB connection only once for single run of application?

Tags: android, greendao

Currently I am creating the greenDAO DB connection in a class (which opens the connection in every static method) and using it wherever I need it. But I am not sure if it's the best way of doing it.
Can anyone suggest a better way of doing it?

My Code:

```
import com.knowlarity.sr.db.dao.DaoMaster;
import com.knowlarity.sr.db.dao.DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper;
import com.knowlarity.sr.db.dao.DaoSession;
import com.knowlarity.sr.db.dao.IEntity;

public class DbUtils {

    private static Object lockCallRecord =new Object();
    private DbUtils(){};

    public static boolean saveEntity(Context context , IEntity entity){
            boolean t=false;
            DevOpenHelper helper=null;
            SQLiteDatabase db=null;
            DaoMaster daoMaster=null;
            DaoSession daoSession =null;
            try{
               helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, IConstant.DB_STRING, null);
               db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
               daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
               daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
               //Some business logic here for fetching and inserting the data.
            }catch (Exception e){
               Log.e("saveEntity", e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }finally{
               if(daoSession!=null)daoSession.clear();
               daoMaster=null;
               if(db.isOpen())db.close();
               helper.close();
            }
            return t;
    }
```

Comment: check this tutorial http://wiki.workassis.com/android-greendao-example/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach causes the database to be loaded very often which is not necessary and may slow down your app significantly.

Open the database once and store it somewhere and request it from there if needed.

Personally I use a global `DaoSession` and local `DaoSession`s. The local `DaoSession`s get used where nothing should remain in the session cache (i.e. persisting a new object into the database, that is likely to be used only very infrequent or performing some queries which will load a lot of entities that are unlikely to be reused again).

**Keep in mind that updating entities in a local `DaoSession` is a bad idea if you use the entity in your global session as well. If you do this the cached entity in your global session won't be updated and you will get wrong results unless you clear the cache of the global session!**

**Thus the safest way is to either just use one `DaoSession` or new `DaoSession`s all the time and to not use a global and local sessions!!!**

A custom application class is a good place, but any other class will also be ok.

This is how I do it:

**class DBHelper:**

```
private SQLiteDatabase _db = null;
private DaoSession _session = null;

private DaoMaster getMaster() {
    if (_db == null) {
        _db = getDatabase(DB_NAME, false);
    }
    return new DaoMaster(_db);
}

public DaoSession getSession(boolean newSession) {
    if (newSession) {
        return getMaster().newSession();
    }
    if (_session == null) {
        _session = getMaster().newSession();
    }
    return _session;
}

private synchronized SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(String name, boolean readOnly) {
    String s = "getDB(" + name + ",readonly=" + (readOnly ? "true" : "false") + ")";
    try {
        readOnly = false;
        Log.i(TAG, s);
        SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper(context, name, null);
        if (readOnly) {
            return helper.getReadableDatabase();
        } else {
            return helper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, s, ex);
        return null;
    } catch (Error err) {
        Log.e(TAG, s, err);
        return null;
    }
}

private class MyOpenHelper extends DaoMaster.OpenHelper {
    public MyOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Create DB-Schema (version "+Integer.toString(DaoMaster.SCHEMA_VERSION)+")");
        super.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Update DB-Schema to version: "+Integer.toString(oldVersion)+"->"+Integer.toString(newVersion));
        switch (oldVersion) {
            case 1:
                db.execSQL(SQL_UPGRADE_1To2);
            case 2:
                db.execSQL(SQL_UPGRADE_2To3);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In application class:

```
private static MyApplication _INSTANCE = null;

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return _INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    _INSTANCE = this;
    // ...
}

private DBHelper _dbHelper = new DBHelper();

public static DaoSession getNewSession() {
    return getInstance()._dbHelper.getSession(true);
}

public static DaoSession getSession() {
    return getInstance()._dbHelper.getSession(false);
}
```

Of course you can also store the DaoMaster instead of the DB itself. This will reduce some small overhead.

I'm using a Singleton-like Application class and static methods to avoid casting the application (`((MyApplication)getApplication())`) every time I use some of the common methods (like accessing the DB).

Comment: could you elaborate more on the global/local approach - how and why do you separate it? I'm trying to implement both DAO and ContentProvider access to the same DB without conflicts and cache inconsistencies. Do you think it can be done with different sessions?

Comment: @WindRider Simplified my usecase was that at some time I had to query a lot of data. The user selected one and afterward I didn't need this data anymore for about 1 hour. So I didn't want that data in my Session-cache.

Comment: @WindRider About your approach: If you write data into your database in one of the two sessions the sessions may be inconsistent as the other session doesn't get notified about the changes and keeps an outdated entity. Probably it's fine to use the same session. As told earlier the 2 session approach was for a very special usecase.

Comment: I think to use one global session and will use content provider for special cases when bulk loading of big amount of rows - this is proved very very fast. I hope not to use the content provider for modifications. This should give me some guarantee for cache consistency. So - DAO for read/write and content provider for read-only.

Comment: @WindRider If your second (local) session is used for just one single read you stay consistent. Otherwise you may read outdated data. Why don't you use the same session?

Comment: Yes, i think a one global session is my way to go. But the content provider could still cause troubles if it updates a row that is cached already. One approach could be to clear the cache after every possible modification coming from the content provider.

Comment: @WindRider If you use just one session, you don't have to care about the cache and modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create your database in your Application class. Then you can create a method to return the DaoSession to get access to the database in other Activities.