# Altered Table Column is not able to access using Greendao-Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

Using onUpgrade in SQLiteOpenHelper, i can alter the table and new column name with a default value is added.

But when i access that particular table inside the activity,it shows only the old column count.As per alteration,it should display 4 (column count).But it shows 3 Only.

My code inside onUpgrade method:

```
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + MyTableDaoDao.TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN 'VRESION_NO' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '11';");
```

// **As im sure that table is altered because when i try to alter it again using the same column name,it shows duplicate column name sqlite exception.**

For getting all columns count:

```
 daoSession.getMyTableDao().getAllColumns().length  // returns old table count
```

How can get the refreshed table details in GreenDAO?.
Is there anyone come across this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot to recreate your dao code from an updated schema.

Greendao doesn't use reflection or scan the database for creating a mapping between database and java. This mapping is created by the dao-generator. So there are two tasks if you want to update your database schema:

1. Update the entity-classes and daos by recreating them with the new schema and increase schema-version.
2. Implement your update strategy in your app, i.e. drop all tables and recreate them or add/change/remove the columns/tables/indexes/... that have changed since the schema-version that was active before (see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24607046/731183) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24137120/731183)).

Comment: That seems correct.You mean if i have an existing table with fields like _id,name,email and a existing DAO files holding this ,then if i alter my  table like adding a new column "age" should recreate new DAO,s and replace the existing DAO's file ,right?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know to update "schema_version", where is that in the documentation? I'm new to greendao and feel like alot of the documentation is very lacking

Comment: @batoutofhell See [schema](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/#Schema), [database setup](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/how-to-get-started/#Setting_up_the_database) and [OpenHelper](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/3.1/org/greenrobot/greendao/database/DatabaseOpenHelper.html). Rock on ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could come up with is that you're getting the columns from the wrong table.

You could try to drop the table and then recreate it with the new column, maybe then it will register. Also think it is easier this way to write dynamic code. (just add the column to a list of Strings and loop trough it when creating the table).

Comment: i want keep old data and add new columns with default values.So dropping table is not possible.And more over ,i have databse in asset folder which is copied at the beginning . So how to tackle  this?

Comment: I'm getting an error when adding a column with quotes around it. So try    ALTER TABLE " + MyTableDaoDao.TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN VRESION_NO INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '11';

Comment: Actually the problem is data insertion after table alteration.It dosent shows any error and inserting as null value.